# inject figwheel's or boot's cljs-repl to arbitrary webpages

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, leiningen, figwheel

Could the leiningen plug-in figwheel or boot's counterpart be used within arbitrary webpages? I'm thinking of it as an replacement of the browser's builtin developer console.

Here is a simple scenario of how I'd imagine this workflow:
You open an arbitrary website in the browser. Beside that, you have a browser repl inside a terminal window, which is provided by one of the tools mentioned above. (I guess they both use 'weasel' for this.)
Inside the terminal one could access the current state of the weppages' DOM.
E.g: `(set! (.. js/window style backgroundColor) "green"))`

I guess this should not be too problematic to archive. However, I faced the following problems:

Both tools do actually just inject a bunch of JavaScript into the users's HTML page. It's basically: The users's ClojureScript compiled to JavaScript plus additional implementation of the hot-reloading mechanism via websockets. The second is just omitted when the project comes into production.

My idea was to just inject the whole bundle to another page.

I used boot for the try.
After setting up the boot's ClojureScript REPL, I opened localhost:port in a browser. It's inital source looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The after main.js has been executed on page-load, many (more than 100) further javaScript tags are injected to the page. My initial idea was to just open another page now, say duckduckgo.com, and inject that one script tag to it, augmented with an absolute path to localhost.
so, at the duckduckgo.com page, inside the developer console I did this:

```
tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "http://localhost:3000/js/main.js";
document.body.appendChild(tag);
```

As expected the script gets injected, and this always leads to the immediate execution of its code. I was expecting that all the other script tags get injected now automatically. Finally the webSockets should be connected to the ClojureScript repl.

However, there's the following error in the browser console: `A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored.`

Indeed, many of the further script tags have been injected. But not all of them. Effectively, the socket connection is not established.

So, it looks like some script tags are injected by the mechanism I used myself (via appendChild), others should be done by `document.write("<script...` The later causes the problem here.

Does anybody know a way to archive this?